# PowerBI RLS Not working with Dynamics 365 PowerBI Dashboard

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, row-level-security

I am doing a POC on RLS (Row Level Security).

1. I have a very basic Report which lists all leads and Their Owners
2. I have a Role Defined with formula as: `[internalemailaddress] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()` on SystemUsers Table.
3. Testing this on Desktop works
4. Publish and Add Users to the Role
5. Use PowerBI Dashboard Option inside Dynamics 365 to show this dashboard inside Dynamics CRM
6. Login via One of the Users which has this PowerBI Role
7. All The Rows are shown and No Filtering Occurs.

Please suggest If I am doing something wrong.

Also please suggest if there is a way via which System Roles/Groups define in CRM/O365 can be reused in PowerBI (e.g. SalesPerson should be able to view only his data, Sales-Manager should be able to get data of all sales person under his territory etc.)

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Using-RLS-with-Dynamics-CRM-Online/td-p/258614

Comment: Reach out to this guy: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/power-bi-dynamic-row-level-security-rls-salesforce-crm-gene-connolly/

Comment: Hello Arun,
Thanks for your reply.That is exactly what i was trying to do,more so... My RLS worked in service and desktop,but not in crm.

Owner of dataset was the key,Once I switched to a new user,it worked as expected.
Probably an oversight due to late night work. 
Thanks for pointing me in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have to change the owner of the dataset to someone else or login/test with a different CRM user to see RLS in action.

Referring [this thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Using-RLS-with-Dynamics-CRM-Online/td-p/258614) in Power BI community:

> RLS wouldn't work on the owner of the dataset. Because the owner can edit both the dataset and reports. RLS aims at controlling the data access rather than something like filtering. You can run "Test as role" to see the effect.

[image]